# Deserialize Newtonsoft.Json on production server not converting quoted numbers

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

This is strange as the behavior is different on my local dev machine vs when we publish to our production server. The json has numbers with double quotes around them. On deserializing to an `int`, the resulting numeric value is correct on my local machine, but is always 0 on the production server, but just for the `MenuId` property...the `Id` property is converted just find (see below). What could cause this?

Models

```
public class MenuViewModel : MenuItemViewModel
{                    
    public int? ParentMenuId { get; set; }
    public string MenuName { get; set; }
 
}
public class MenuItemViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MenuId { get; set; }
}
```

Json

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Orders",
        "Id": "53",
        "MenuId": "53"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Customers",
        "Id": "54",
        "MenuId": "54"
    },
]
```

debugging output after deserialization - LOCAL MACHINE

```
Menus to Save - after convert to JSON: 
Id: 53 Name: Orders MenuId: 53;
Id: 54 Name: Customers MenuId: 53
```

debugging output after deserialization - PRODUCTION MACHINE

```
Menus to Save - after convert to JSON: 
Id: 53 Name: Orders MenuId: 0;
Id: 54 Name: Customers MenuId: 0
```

```
_logger.Debug($"Menus to Save - before convert to JSON: {viewModel.MenuListDetail}.");

viewModel.menulist = ConvertJSonToObject<List<MenuViewModel>>(viewModel.MenuListDetail);

string menuList = String.Join("; ", viewModel.menulist.Select(m => "Id: " + m.Id + " Name: " + m.Name + " MenuId: " + m.MenuId));

 _logger.Debug($"Menus to Save - after convert to JSON: {menuList}");
```

```
public T ConvertJSonToObject<T>(string jsonString) { 
   T obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString);
   return obj;
}
```

Comment: are the local and production machines using the same version of the library? are they running in the same culture?

Comment: I am sure that the problem is that viewModel.MenuListDetail object doesn't receive the same data from production as it is in a local mashine. Check database and all way from db.

Comment: @MarcGravell - yes, just published the code and dlls from Local to Production.

Comment: @Serge - the debugging output is log4net logging output from production, not a local debug console.

Comment: @crichavin I can not see this data "Menus to Save - before convert to JSON" and I see for example that your class has MenuName  property, but json just Name,  and wondering what else is not the same as you posted?

Comment: 1) Are you certain you are running the exact same method `ConvertJSonToObject<T>(string jsonString)` both locally and on the server?  Or are you actually using asp.net model binding on the server?  2) If actually using  `ConvertJSonToObject<T>()` in both places, what is the value of [`JsonConvert.DefaultSettings`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DefaultSettings.htm) locally and on the server?  Could the server have default settings that you do not have locally?

Comment: @dbc - Bingo! There was a part of the application that gets called in the production environment that was setting DefaultSettings to use some custom resolvers instead of using an instance based approach, upsetting Json deserialization throughout the app. But on my local, I wasn't calling that method as it was unrelated to the section I was working on. If you want to make an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks again! This was a hard one to track down.